# Supervised vegetation classification in R

Tags: raster, r, classification

I am using the `RStoolbox` function `superClass` to create a vegetation class map in `R`. After I run the code and plot, I see that the river is being classified too, even though none of the `training points` lie on the river nor do I have class called `water` in my training data. How can I fix this? On a side note I also tried the `random forest` package, but it fails due to the limitation of categorical predictors.

```
library(RStoolbox)
library(raster)

# Bring in the training data
species_training = readOGR("path", layer = "Species_Training_Point")

# Bring in the RGB raster
RGB = raster::brick("path/RGB.tif")
RGB_Stack = raster::stack(RGB$band_1,
                          RGB$band_2,
                          RGB$band_3)

# Using the supervised classification using the maximum likelihood model 
Species_SC = superClass(img = RGB_Stack , model = "mlc", trainData = species_training, responseCol = "Species")

plot(Species_SC$map)
```

[image]

Comment: I've got `RStoolbox` but not `RSToolbox` with a capital `T`. Does `library(RSToolbox)` really work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask a model to predict over a raster, it will predict over the entire raster. It doesn't know there's a river there.

Its prediction for location-types that you haven't trained on will be inaccurate. Maybe the nearest class for the river is "desert", and it will think rivers are deserts.

Either add some points on the river (or other water elements) to your training data as a new class, or if you have a vector map of the river, you could probably use that to `mask` the river area from the raster map, setting it to `NA` in the raster.

Another option would be to get the prediction probabilities from `superClass` using `predType="prob"` and then you can refine your idea of a class as being above a certain threshold, rather than the largest probability.

For example if all three class probabilities are 0.33, the model really doesn't know. You might find a river pixel is A with p=0.33, B with p=0.32 and C with p=0.34, and so you could set that to a new class "unsure" with some raster arithmetic. Otherwise that pixel will be classed a "C" because its the largest of those three probabilities.

The single most important consideration, however, is *what you are going to use this classification for*, because that must **always** be the driving force for any data analysis.